Erro ao adicionar campo 'DATAREVERIFICACAO': ERROR 000852:
Erro ao adicionar campo 'DATAREVERIFICACAO': ERROR 000852: Não é possível adicionar o campo DATAREVERIFICACAO para GISADMIN.Survey.
Ocorreu um erro ao executar (AddField).
Esse erro é obtido através da execução desse código no notebook do ArcGIS Pro 3.0.0 versão 2022:
#Código forms 
Import arcpy.

#colocar caminhos das camadas 
Camada_origem = "r"C:\Users\nicolasoliveira\Documents\ArcGIS\Projects\form"
Camada_destino = "r"C:\Users\nicolasoliveira\Documents\ArcGIS\Projects\form"


Define copiar_atributos():
    """
    Copia todos os atributos e a geometria da camada de origem para a camada de destino, excluindo o campo 'ID'.
    Cria os campos ausentes na camada de destino, caso necessário.
    """
    try:
        Verificar se a camada de destino existe.
        if arcpy.Exists(camada_destino):
            # Iniciar uma sessão de edição.
            Workspace = arcpy.Describe(camada_destino).path
            With arcpy.da.Editor(workspace) as editor:
                print("Sessão de edição iniciada.")
                
                #obter campos da camada de origem
                Campos_origem = [field.name for field in arcpy.ListFields(camada_origem)]
                #Obter campos da camada de destino.
                Campos_destino = [field.name for field in arcpy.ListFields(camada_destino)]
                
                Excluir o campo 'ID' e outros campos gerenciados pelo sistema.
                Campos_excluir = ['ID', 'OBJECTID', 'FID', 'GlobalID', 'Shape', 'Shape_Length', 'Shape_Area']
                Campos_origem = [campo for campo in campos_origem if campo not in campos_excluir]
                
                #verificar campos ausentes e criar na camada de destino.
                Campos_faltantes = [campo for campo in campos_origem if campo not in campos_destino]
                for campo in campos_faltantes:
                    Campo_obj = arcpy.ListFields(camada_origem, campo)[0]
                    arcpy.AddField_management(camada_destino, campo, campo_obj.type)
                    print(f"Campo '{campo}' adicionado à camada de destino.")

                #apagar os registros existentes na camada de destino.
                arcpy.management.DeleteRows(camada_destino)
                print(f"Registros existentes na camada de destino '{camada_destino}' foram apagados.")

                # Usar um cursor de leitura na camada de origem.
                With arcpy.da.SearchCursor(camada_origem, campos_origem) as cursor_origem:
                    # Usar um cursor de inserção na camada de destino.
                    With arcpy.da.InsertCursor(camada_destino, campos_origem) as cursor_destino:
                        for linha in cursor_origem:
                            Cursor_destino.insertRow(linha)
                            print(f"Registro copiado: {linha}")
                
                print(f"Todos os atributos da camada '{camada_origem}' foram copiados para '{camada_destino}', excluindo o campo 'ID'.")
        Else:
            print(f"A camada de destino '{camada_destino}' não existe.")
    Except Exception as e:
        print(f"Erro ao copiar atributos: {e}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Copiar_atributos()

Mesmo com as permissões já liberadas pelo ADM do banco, o código não consegue fazer essa operação nas camadas quando estão no banco, porém quando essa camada é movida para a máquina local, o código funciona.
Foram inúmeras tentativas em relação à autorização, até com o perfil do ADM foi efetuada a execução do código e mesmo assim não funcionou. Já pesquisei sobre o erro tanto pelo GPT e outras IAS como também em outros sites e blogs, e o que encontro é falando que o erro é problema de permissão, porém a camada já está com todas as autorizações.

Uma forma encontrada de remediar isso dentro do ArcGIS foi uma solução No code, onde a ferramenta Anexar foi implementada dentro do Model Builder, configurada para pegar informações da camada origem e atualizar na camada destino através da reconciliação.
